# OpenMP parallel for inside do-while

Tags: c++, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to refactor a OpenMP-based program and encountered a terrible scalability issue. The following (obviously not very meaningful) OpenMP program seems to reproduce the problem. Of course, the tiny sample code can be rewritten as a nested for-loop and using `collapse(2)` almost perfect scalability can be achieved. However, the original program I am working on does not allow to do that.

Therefore, I am looking for a fix, the keeps the do-while structure. From my understanding, OpenMP should be smart enough to keep the threads alive between the iterations and I expected good scalability. Why is this not the case?

```c
int main() {
    const int N = 6000;
    const int MAX_ITER = 2000000;
    double max = DBL_MIN;

    int iter = 0;
    do {
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(max:max) schedule(static)
        for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
            max = MAX(max, 3.3*i);
        }
    ++iter;
    } while(iter < MAX_ITER);

    printf("max=%f\n", max);
}
```

I have measured the following runtimes with Cray compiler Version 8.3.4.

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 : 0m21.535s
OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 : 0m12.191s
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 : 0m9.610s
OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 : 0m9.767s 
OMP_NUM_THREADS=16: 0m13.571s
```

This seems to be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345002/parallel-for-inside-a-while-using-openmp-on-c). Thanks in advance. Help is appreciated! :)

Comment: How many threads/cores do you have on your physical machine? Also, if you are only doing very little work inside your `for` loop, you probably will not get good scalability.

Comment: I have 32 cores divided between 2 CPUs. Every core has 2 hyperthreading threads. CPU is Intel Xeon E5-2698v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your could go for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define MAX( a, b ) ((a)>(b))?(a):(b)

int main() {
    const int N = 6000;
    const int MAX_ITER = 2000000;
    double max = DBL_MIN;

    #pragma omp parallel reduction( max : max )
    {
        int iter = 0;
        int nbth = omp_get_num_threads();
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        int myMaxIter = MAX_ITER / nbth;
        if ( tid < MAX_ITER % nbth ) myMaxIter++;
        int chunk = N / nbth;
        do {
            #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,chunk) nowait
            for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
                max = MAX(max, 3.3*i);
            }
            ++iter;
        } while(iter < myMaxIter);
    }
    printf("max=%f\n", max);
}
```

I'm pretty sure scalability should improve notoriously.

NB: I had to come back to this a few times since I realised that the number of iterations for the outer loop (the do-while one) being potentially different for the different threads, it was of crucial importance that the scheduling of the `omp for` loop wasn't static, otherwise, there was a potential for deadlock at the last iteration.
I did a few tests and I think that the proposed solution is both safe and effective.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I think I found a solution based on it. Is there an explanation why my original code performed terrible? Is it the fact that in my version many threads were created whenever `parallel` was entered? Why were the threads not kept between the `parallel ` regions?

Comment: That's the way OpenMP works... That's the bases of its the fork-join model. Out of curiosity, could you post your solution?

Comment: Thanks. Then I misunderstood something. The code is still work in progress. It's a hybrid OpenMP+MPI project. Can post the complete code when I finished the work.

Comment: You can have a look at the code here: http://pastebin.com/yb0BxvrZ - Comments are very welcome since I am learning OpenMP+MPI. It's hybrid Gauss-Seidel+SOR.

Comment: Looks good to me. You should consider proposing it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you are interested in actual comments. Just two quick ones though: 1/ `omp master` doesn't imply any barrier at the end so be careful that other threads might get started on what follows before the master parts is done; and 2/ which is strongly connect with my 1st point, be careful that whenever a non-blocking communication has been initiated, you **must not** use the communication buffers until the communication is completed. I didn't check if it is the case here, but just saying.

Comment: Thank you. Nice suggestion. I'll post it there. /2 should not be a problem. And I learned /1 the hard way, there was a problem with updating `maxdelta`. But I eventually found out! :)

Comment: You can now find it here if you want to follow the discussion: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105462/learning-openmpmpi-feedback-and-comments-on-gauss-seidelsor